# Hardness vs testability ?

Tags: property-testing

How does hardness plays role in testability?

Intuitively, it seems that for the problems which have exact efficient algorithm, there is more hope to get constant query (or, relatively a small number of queries) testing algorithm (in [property testing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Property_testing) framework).

But here is the counterexample, testing if a graph is $k$-colorable 
(which is a hard problem) there is a constant query testing algorithm (see [paper](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.15.4694)), while for testing if given numbers are sorted $O(\frac{1}{\epsilon}\lg n)$ queries are required (see [paper](http://www.eccc.hpi-web.de/report/1999/017/)) .

So, does hardness plays any role in testability, or is completely orthogonal to it?